# Export Exchange Public folders to a network drive, sharepoint, or a PST

Tags: sharepoint, exchange-2010, public-folders, outlook

I have a single user who is using 110Gb of data in public folders, and the Exchange admin (me) is persuading them to put that data elsewhere.

What options are there for exporting this data?

What utilities exist?

Comment: Is that supposed to be 110GB? Gb are 8 times smaller than GB.

Comment: What kind of data?  110 GB of emails?

Comment: @ChrisS - What is the unit of measurement of ExFolder's property `PR_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED` and `Total Calculated Size Of Items` in the content report?  In this case lets round up ;)

Comment: @Christopher Could be Freedocs, emails, etc.

Comment: A file server would be the best solution here.

On a personal note I suggest wandering around your office muttering "Email is not a file distribution system" and "Email is not archival storage" under your breath, brandishing various weapons.  
Eventually people will get the hint. (Or you'll snap and kill them. Either way, dead people can be archived and you free up the storage!)

Comment: LARTing the user is a must here. But the question is about *how* to actually get that data out of Exchange and move them to a file server.

Answer (score 3):

Outlook can do that. Exchange on its own can't. There probably are third-party utilities around that can help, but using Outlook is probably the easiest approach.

Just open Outlook, create a PST file, right-click on the PF you want to export, select "Copy Folder" and place it in the PST archive.

Oh, and don't try to put all of that data into a single PST file. It will **not** end well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of third party tools that are available in the market to solve this kind of the problem and I have also faced a similar kind of situation to move my EDB of size 120 GB to a PST and I used a third party tool which easily copied my EDB to PST format.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about any utilities but you can export data into PST format using the Import/Export Wizard of Exchange,

1) Select the File or mailbox want to Export.

2) Then Go for Select PST in the Import & Export wizard

3) In the Export Outlook Data File dialog box, selec public folder that needs to be exported.

**Note:** Select the Mailbox associated with Include Subfolders option (available at the bottom section & Continue further.

4) Note Browse the Destination path to store exported Public folder of PST File 
Next, click on the Browse button to select the destination path for storing the exported Public Folders as PST files.

5) Select option to Allow or Disallow the Duplicates Elements.
6) Wait till the process is completed

But Problem arise when, user import PST file into Outlook, as Different Outlook 
An application has the different limit of PST, otherwise, it starts getting hanging and performance of application affected

So you need to Split the PST File so that data can be managed properly that not possible above manual process, To split in Outlook Two option are available:

a) Divide PST File into Multiple Parts by Using Archive Feature
b) Split Outlook PST File into Smaller Parts by Using Import & Export Option

A user can [visit](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Split-Outlook-PST-File-812fa104) to know complete steps of above process, as a process are lengthy.